# Loading a Html page in a div of an another html page by calling from a different html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have three html pages those are  `index.html`, `page1.html` and `page2.html`.

Currently I am on `page2.html` and have a list of items with each hyperlinking to some pages. Say one links to `page1.html`.

Is it possible to load `page1.html` in a `div` which is in `index.html` from `page2.html`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is possible depending on how you want them to be loaded. Angularjs/react are some of the few famous examples

Comment: can you please share some examples.

Comment: You can find such examples everywhere on web. For angular 1 (which is now outdated) i followed his posts https://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToAngular/exampleViewer/#/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `.load()` for this

```
$('#div').load('pageUrl');
```

> Or if you need any `callback` then you can use

```
$('#div').load('pageUrl', function(){
    // your code here
});
```

For detail reference you can [click here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: yeah but how will you find the div of an another page?

Comment: You can read all option on `jquery.load()`  http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible,

You can request index.html using jQuery ajax as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/index.html"
}).done(function(htmlData) {
    var htmlContent = $.parseHTML(htmlData).find("div"); // Here you pass the div reference of content you want to load
    $("div.targetDiv").html(htmlContent);
});
```